# Is there any specific API to get multiple documents from a single Database in Marklogic DB?

Tags: database, nosql, marklogic, document, rest

I am trying to find a specific Rest API that can help to get multiple documents from a single database in Marklogic DB.
Kindly share the specific endpoint. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you know the document uris, you can feed them all in a single call to [/v1/documents](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents):

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/documents

> uri+   One or more URIs for documents in the database. If you specify multiple URIs, the Accept header must be multipart/mixed.

If you have search criteria, you can use [/v1/search](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search) instead, which allows paging through a large result set. It doesn't return full documents by default, but you can specify an Accept header of multipart/mixed, use view/format settings, and/or search options to influence its behavior:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/search

HTH!